# TypeError: Network request failed using fetch ReactNative and Laravel response

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, request, postman

I am posting data to Laravel and expect a success response, but it catches the exception **TypeError: Network request failed**. *Using get methods and login post methods using Laravel passport works all fine.*

- Adding 'Content-Type': 'application/json' to headers creates Network request failed for the login methods.
- Postman returns valid errors or success, so works totally as expected.
- Debugging showed that the request has been sent to Laravel and routing is correct as Visual Studio Code debugger stops at a breakpoint at return response.

```php
public function postMessages()
{
    ...

    return response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
}
```

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
    Route::post('messages', 'Api\ChatController@postMessages');
});
```

```
export const fetchApi = async (endPoint, method = 'get', body = {}) => {
    const accessToken = authSelectors.get().tokens.access.value;
    const accessType = authSelectors.get().tokens.access.type;
    let headers = {
      ...(accessToken &&
      {
        Authorization: `${accessType} ${accessToken}`
      } 
      )
    };
    let response;
    if (method=='get' || Object.keys(body)==0 ) {
        response = await fetch(`${apiConfig.url}${endPoint}`, {
            method: method,
            headers: headers
        });
    } else {
        var formData = new FormData();
        Object.keys(body).forEach(type => {
            formData.append(type, body[type]);
        });
        response = await fetch(`${apiConfig.url}${endPoint}`, {
            method: method,
            headers: headers,
            body: formData
        });
        console.log('fetch response: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    let responseJsonData = await response.json();
    return responseJsonData;
}
```

```
export const postMessages = (eidug, type, name, messages) => fetchApi('/message', 'post', {
    'eidug': eidug,
    'type': type,
    'name': name,
    'messages': messages
});
```

I expect a response without any exception like Postman. What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled CORS in the backend? Once open inspect->network and then run fetch. Show if there are any errors.

Comment: The post methods for login are working. I used some library for sending the response (IssueTokenTrait). Those methods have status 200, responseContenType: application/json, responseHeaders, ... The ```response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);```arrives with status 0, reponse null, no responseHeaders at the inspect network.

Comment: It was not necessary to use any cors middleware. Perhaps this is normal when using Laravel Passport and API token verification. The problem seemed to be a missing parameter. The validate function did not give any clear error, but the messages parameter was missing as I did not use JSON.stringify to pass an array from react-native to laravel... A bit strange it did not go to error_log, but it is solved :)